# C# UWP XAML is it possible to make bidirectional scroll gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

is it possible to make gridview in UWP that scrolls horizontal and vertical.

Comment: It's got a scrollviewer, or you could even embed it in another if that's easier, so yes it is possible.

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't clear enough. :) I need bidirectional scroll at the same time. I was able to get scrolls with Grid and drawing fields programmatically, but it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `ScrollViewer` inside the `GridView` directly like this:

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="SteelBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="SteelBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="SteelBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="SteelBlue"/>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="SteelBlue"/>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah possible.But in UWP the `HorizontalScrollMode` is `Disabled` for many controls. So to enable it you can create a style for the control you use and make the setter of `HorizontalScrollMode` to `Enabled`. For a `GridView` it will look like this.

```
<Style x:Key="ShapesButtonGridViewStyle" TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                            <ItemsPresenter FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}" FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}" HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```